# Android: Check for pending push notifications in GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM push notification in my app. It's working fine. In some scenarios, notification should be received immediately, but I receive it very late. Is there anyway to check whether I have notification in my GCM Queue ?

Note:

I understand that, **Push notification** mechanism is completely to overcome **Polling** mechanism. But curious to know whether the above thing is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Messaging server returns a response for each message you send to it. That message tells you whether the message was accepted or rejected by the server (it doesn't tell whether it was actually delivered to the device) and also specifies the type of error if any.

You may check the Offical Google Cloud Messaging documentation: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/#receipts

Comment: You may refer to this Stack overflow ticket. Seems like you have the same inquiry. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135825/can-my-server-receive-the-acknowledgement-from-the-gcm-once-the-intended-message)

Comment: Also found this related ticket, How to avoid delay in Android GCM messages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560448/how-to-avoid-delay-in-android-gcm-messages-change-heartbeat