# GCM Message Delivery Confirmation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing push notifications with **Google Cloud Messaging**. I am simply testing with their demo applicaitons on official site.
All is working well.
But, has anyone idea of how to gurantee the delivery of message, in anyway?
Or can we invoke server to let know once the message are delivered in device, and will it be reliable approach?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the answer on [Android GCM delivery monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967883/android-gcm-delivery-monitoring).

"They don't guarantee delivery but they try for a max of 4 weeks to deliver the message depending on the duration you set in the message you send to Google's GCM servers and if you wish to let Google keep the data for eventual delivery of msg to the device in case the device was offline when the message was to be delivered."

Answer (score 2):

Google has added support so that you can receive delivery receipts from Cloud Connection Server (CCS):

> You can use upstream messaging to get delivery receipts (sent from CCS to your 3rd party app server) when a device confirms that it received a message sent by CCS. 
>   To enable this feature, the message your 3rd-party app server sends to CCS must include a field called "delivery_receipt_requested". When this field is set to true, CCS sends a delivery receipt when a device confirms that it received a particular message.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#receipts

Comment: have you ever test delivery receipts feature? In my test program it shows very unstable results. Is seems delivery confirms randomly and time to time.

Comment: But how we set the app server to receive those delivery confirmation, I see none mentioned in the document.