# Android Google - Cloud Messaging Report

Tags: android, push-notification, message, google-cloud-messaging

I had implemented Google Cloud Messaging in one of my application and that is working fine. But my client reported that they are not getting notifications sometimes.

So I am confused because its working fine and getting all notifications here.

My question is :- Is there any way to trace the message has been send or not ? Just like in Amazon AWS console we can get the status of each mail, message we sent.

Can any one please help me ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of how to trace the confirmation but GCM Push service is not 100% reliable. There is a beautiful answer on [Android GCM delivery monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967883/android-gcm-delivery-monitoring) question by @[Nitin Sethi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035935/nitin-sethi). I am quoting him here:

Google does not guarantee delivery but they try for a max of 4 weeks to deliver the message. It depends on the duration that you set in the message you send to Google's GCM servers for which data would be available to them. It also depends on whether you wish to let Google keep the data for eventual delivery of message to the device, in case the device was offline when the message was to be delivered.

However, there are certain conditions under which the GCM messages are not delivered:

1. Background data is unchecked under Account and Sync settings.
2. Prior to 4.0.4.(ICS), a Google account on the device is a pre-requisite for GCM. Maybe, Users are not logged into their Google account.

See [Google I/O 2012 - Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM)  for more.

**Update**

Although Google might not give you the stats whether the Push was delivered successfully or not, there might way to report back to your server with the timestamp of the received push. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068424/1306419 answer for that idea.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. But using the same device, same application. Sometimes notification not working ...