# How reliable is CGM RegistrationID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am currently using GCM to push adn get data from an android app, however i am finding the GCM registration process to be very unreliable practically 1/7 times i get a null registration id.

so the question is how to guarantee getting a GCM registration id.

```
public String RegisID() {

            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getActivity());
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

                Log.d("111", msg);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }

            return regid;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Android GCM delivery monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967883/android-gcm-delivery-monitoring) question. Basically the gist of the answers is that Google doesn't guarantee delivery but they tries for few weeks to deliver the message depending on the duration you set in the message.

If you really want to confirm whether a message was delivered or not, have push ID in the push message itself. When sending the message from your server, store a time stamp corresponding to that push ID. When user receives the push message, send a message back to your server(with push ID and some other parameter) saying that the push message with that particular push ID has been received.

On server side keep track of the time stamp. If the difference between time stamp of a push message and current time crosses your set limit, send that particular message again from your server. Its a hectic method!

Hope it gives you some idea.

Comment: thanks for the fast response , however you seem to have missed my question. am asking about the registration id for each mobile phone. it seems to give service unavailable more than it should. the reliability of sending and receiving data by gcm is good.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Your question is more about the first step. Which version of ANdroid are you testingon?

Comment: Min api 12 , doing most denuging on a v4.3 and v4.2.2 devices